Primary 6 Asia-Pacific Olympiad Question - Minimizing distance between 7 points
Primary mathematics teacher here specializing in training for Olympiads.
This question has long bothered me because the answer is given but the working has never been explained.

There are 5 schools between School A and School G. The seven schools are whole number of kilometers from each other along a straight line. The schools are spaced in such a way that if one knows the distance between any two schools, he can identify the two schools. What is the shortest distance between A and G?

Some observations that immediately come to mind:

We can easily get an initial solution by assuming the first distance is 1 then simply using the next available whole number for the next distance. So if the first distance = 1, 2nd distance = 2, the third distance cannot be 3 so we can assume 4, etc. This leads to the following solution: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10 which sums up to 30. This serves as an upper bound for an optimal solution, so we can now try to see if we can do better than 30 and ignore any result that returns 30 or above.




Origin (column) / Destination (row)
B
C
D
E
F
G




A
1
3
7
12
20
30


B
x
2
6
11
19
29


C
x
x
4
9
17
27


D
x
x
x
5
13
23


E
x
x
x
x
8
18


F
x
x
x
x
x
10




At the same time, we can't get a more efficient solution than 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21, so any solution found must be from 21 to 30 km.

The answer given in the answer key is (spoiler):

 25, which I was eventually able to get as 3 + 1 + 8 + 6 + 5 + 2

Honestly, without the key I would not have known that the given answer was optimal. Is there a way to prove that there is no shorter distance possible? And is there a more efficient way to test possible solutions other than simply iterating through every possible combination?
I am generally going to be trying to explain this problem to sixth graders, but I am open to seeing solutions that involve higher-level math, if needed.

$1+2+3+4+5+6$ is not a solution per the constraints.

@sku Yes. That is a lower bound, not a solution, which comes from the fact that there must be $21$ distinct distances so the largest must be at least $21$.

This is known as a Golomb ruler, and for 7 schools the minimum distance is 25. There are several layouts (so not just the answer that was stated). It takes some effort to prove that 25 is indeed the minimum. Was this a proof based question, or just asking for a numerical answer?

@CalvinLin I wanted a proof (more for my own curiosity than for my students).  But the link is very helpful and it will suffice!

This can be formulated and solved to global optimality as a (Mixed-)Integer Linear Programming problem (MILP)). Here are five different optimal solutions I got from different solvers: [4,9,15,22,23,25], [3,4,12,18,23,25],[1,4,10,18,23,25].[2,6,9,14,24,25],[1,11,16,19,23,25].

@MarkL.Stone would you mind sharing the formulation of the LP?

Based on the references from the Wikipedia article, it looks as though the "proof" was done by manual search, so I guess that answers my question about the proof.

Solving follow-on MILPs shows that among optimal solutions, the sum of the first 5 elements can be as small as 52 and as large as 73.

@Javier I The margins of the comments are not ample enough to contain the formulation.

@Javier I Here is YALMIP code. x=intvar(6,1);optimize([alldifferent([x(2)-x(1);x(3)-x(1:2);x(4)-x(1:3);x(5)-x(1:4);x(6)-x(1:5);x(1:6)]),x>=1,diff(x)>=1],x(6));    alldifferent introduces 210 (=21*20/2) binary variables to enforce that all 21 distances which need to be different are; it uses the binary variables in Big M logic modeling to do that.
